# Bind rows based on conditions with data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have 2 data tables that I would like to merge by binding rows. The dput's are given below:

```
    >dput(x)
    structure(list(NN = c("test", "test", "test", "test", "test"), 
    gpn = c("gas", "gas", "gas", "gas", "gas"), sitename = c("agip", 
    "agip", "agip", "agip", "agip"), code = c("F123", "F123", 
    "F123", "F123", "F123"), Brand = c("bp", "shell", "ionic", 
    "meta", "robo"), starttime = structure(c(1533097609, 1533118867, 
    1533183999, 1533270359, 1533356437), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), endtime = structure(c(1533118867, 
    1533183999, 1533270359, 1533356437, 1533443068), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), price = c(1.592, 1.592, 1.598, 1.598, 
    1.598), otherprice = c(1.998, 2.11, 2.114, 2.134, 1.989)), .Names = c("NN", 
"gpn", "sitename", "code", "Brand", "starttime", "endtime", "price", 
"otherprice"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000025c0788>)



>dput(y)

structure(list(NN = c("test", "test", "test", "test", "test"), 
gpn = c("gas", "gas", "gas", "gas", "gas"), sitename = c("agip", 
"agip", "agip", "agip", "agip"), code = c("F123", "F123", 
"F123", "F123", "F123"), Brand = c("dino", "dino", "dino", 
"dino", "dino"), otherprice = c(1.987, 2.456, 3.456, 1.989, 
1.99), starttime = structure(c(1533097399, 1533118999, 1533184999, 
1533271999, 1533359357), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), endtime = structure(c(1533118100, 1533182999, 
1533270000, 1533356000, 1533443000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("NN", "gpn", "sitename",
```

"code", "Brand", "otherprice", "starttime", "endtime"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = )

I would like to bind rows from y to x such that the following matches:

pseudo code:

If(NN, code from 'x' matches NN, code from 'y') & 'x$starttime' < 'y$starttime' & 'x$endtime' > 'y$endtime'

Then get NN, code, brand, price from 'y' and the resulting frame will become:

```
NN    gpn    sitename   code   Brand        starttime          endtime price otherprice
 test gas     agip      F123    bp    01/08/2018 05:26 01/08/2018 11:21 1.592      1.998
 test gas     agip      F123   shell 01/08/2018 11:21 02/08/2018 05:26 1.592      2.110
 test gas     agip      F123   Ionic 02/08/2018 05:26 03/08/2018 05:25 1.598      2.114
 test gas     agip      F123    meta 03/08/2018 05:25 04/08/2018 05:20 1.598      2.134
 test gas     agip      F123    robo 04/08/2018 05:20 05/08/2018 05:24 1.598      1.989
 test gas     agip      F123    dino 01/08/2018 05:26 01/08/2018 11:21 1.592      1.987
 test gas     agip      F123    dino 01/08/2018 11:21 02/08/2018 05:26 1.592      2.456
 test gas     agip      F123    dino 02/08/2018 05:26 03/08/2018 05:25 1.598      3.456
 test gas     agip      F123    dino 03/08/2018 05:25 04/08/2018 05:20 1.598      1.989
test gas     agip       F123    dino 04/08/2018 05:20 05/08/2018 05:24 1.598      1.990
```

I have checked `InsertRow` and `rbind` but neither works.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the datasets it seems that a good solution is to just `rbind` the datasets while using `merge` to condition the datasets on the start/end time restrictions. In the example below, the `rbind` function nests the `merge` conditioning for the start and end dates:

```
library('data.table')
z <- rbind(
  x = x,
  y = merge(x[, .(code, starttime.x = starttime, endtime.x = endtime, price)], y, 
            by = 'code',
            allow.cartesian = TRUE,
            all.x = TRUE)[starttime.x < starttime & endtime.x > endtime,
                          .SD,
                          .SDcols = c(paste0(names(y)), 'price')])
z
```

Output:

```
     NN gpn sitename code Brand           starttime             endtime price otherprice
1: test gas     agip F123    bp 2018-08-01 00:26:49 2018-08-01 06:21:07 1.592      1.998
2: test gas     agip F123 shell 2018-08-01 06:21:07 2018-08-02 00:26:39 1.592      2.110
3: test gas     agip F123 ionic 2018-08-02 00:26:39 2018-08-03 00:25:59 1.598      2.114
4: test gas     agip F123  meta 2018-08-03 00:25:59 2018-08-04 00:20:37 1.598      2.134
5: test gas     agip F123  robo 2018-08-04 00:20:37 2018-08-05 00:24:28 1.598      1.989
6: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-01 06:23:19 2018-08-02 00:09:59 1.592      2.456
7: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-02 00:43:19 2018-08-03 00:20:00 1.598      3.456
8: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-03 00:53:19 2018-08-04 00:13:20 1.598      1.989
9: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-04 01:09:17 2018-08-05 00:23:20 1.598      1.990
```

Comment: OK. This looks better but still there a couple of things. 

1. let's say we rename 'y$price' to 'y$otherprice' and the 'price' should be from 'x' only then how can we achieve that?


2. The merge should be left-join meaning all the rows from 'x' should be returned.


Any ideas on how to adjust the code to accommodate for above mentioned changes. Thanks

Comment: Lets use the following dput for 'y' which I have updated in question.

Comment: Ok- I adjusted the code to match the new data. "Price" now refers only to the values from the "x" table. The left join is achieved by setting the `all.x` option to TRUE in the `merge` function.

Comment: This looks good but still is missing one observation from 'x' which did not match an observation in 'y'. So the total observations should be 9 in the result as the observation from 'y' that did not match any in 'x' should be dropped only while keeping all rows from x. Thanks.

Comment: I think 'all.x' is not working as the merge is performing an interaction as in only rows that matches. This is just a guess. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I removed the start/end subsetting in the "x" element, which I think was preventing all the rows from showing up. The `unique` just ensures you don't get duplicate entries. I think you could also just substitute the first argument with simply "x", since the merge is no longer doing anything in this example. What do you think?

Comment: Looks like the previous solution was better as the new one is return only 5 rows. One row from x that did not match and remaining of y that matched. All we need is all the rows from x. In other words, x should be returned as it is while only observations from 'y' matching the criteria should be binded with x.

Comment: I am getting 9 rows with the current solution-- double check you aren't using a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

We can merge using `dplyr`, however there are few caveats due to the structure provided. From `dput()`, we see that `y` does not have the `sitename` variable, `starttime` and `starttime` are factors and need to be converted to posixct, and the variable `brand` in `y` has a lowercase "b" but `Brand` in `x` has an upper-case "B".

Accommodating for these observations, we can do the following:

```
# Change time to posixct to be consistent with x. 
# NOTE: You may have to adjust the time zone
y$starttime = as.POSIXct(y$starttime)
y$endtime = as.POSIXct(y$endtime)

# Chance 'brand' to 'Brand'
colnames(y)[colnames(y)=="brand"] = "Brand"

# Change other variabes as mentioned in commen
y$otherprice = y$price
y$price = x$price
y$sitename = x$sitename
```

We can create subsets which satisfy the criteria mentioned (i.e. select the subset of `x` and `y` where `x$starttime < y$starttime` and `x$endtime > y$endtime`)

```
# Create subsets which match criteria
x.subset = subset(x, subset = x$starttime < y$starttime & x$endtime > y$endtime)
y.subset = subset(y, subset = x$starttime < y$starttime & x$endtime > y$endtime)
```

Now we can bind the subsets together

```
# Row bind
library(dplyr)
z = dplyr::bind_rows(x.subset, y.subset)
> z
      NN gpn sitename code Brand           starttime             endtime price otherprice
 1: test gas     agip F123    bp 2018-08-01 00:26:49 2018-08-01 06:21:07 1.592      1.998
 2: test gas     agip F123 shell 2018-08-01 06:21:07 2018-08-02 00:26:39 1.592      2.110
 3: test gas     agip F123 ionic 2018-08-02 00:26:39 2018-08-03 00:25:59 1.598      2.114
 4: test gas     agip F123  meta 2018-08-03 00:25:59 2018-08-04 00:20:37 1.598      2.134
 5: test gas     agip F123  robo 2018-08-04 00:20:37 2018-08-05 00:24:28 1.598      1.989
 6: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-01 00:33:19 2018-08-01 06:08:20 1.592      1.987
 7: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-01 06:23:19 2018-08-02 00:09:59 1.592      2.456
 8: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-02 00:43:19 2018-08-03 00:20:00 1.598      3.456
 9: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-03 00:53:19 2018-08-04 00:13:20 1.598      1.989
10: test gas     agip F123  dino 2018-08-04 01:09:17 2018-08-05 00:23:20 1.598      1.990
```

Comment: All looks good but the price from y should go into "otherprice" column and "price" should be the same as to what was the price for a site in "x".  For sitename, we can consider it's same. Also, the condition requires to check if the starttime in "x" is less than starttime in "y" and "endtime" in "x" is greater than endtime in "y". How can I define that condition while doing rbind?

Comment: @syebill code modified to accommodate requested changes.

Comment: I have changed the structure as well. An important thing is the check for times. Any idea on how to adjust it? The new dput's reflect proper data types. Also the above solution works the only thing missing is the time checks. Do you suggest putting the rbind within an "if_else" statement?

Comment: @syebill could you please elaborate on the time check's you're referring to?

Comment: Yes. The "x" table has start and end times as well as "y". The check is as follows The rows should be binded if"x$starttime < y$starttime and "x$endtime > y$endtime". I hope this clarifies. So once this condition is met than rbind should happen. Thanks:

Comment: I think that you can solve this with an `if else` statement like you mentioned.

Comment: @syebill : I have edited my answer and added more code. There is now a filtering stage where we select subsets of `x` and `y` which satisfy the criteria mentioned in your comment, then we merge the subsets together. This should solve the problem. Please let me know.

Comment: The subset may have a limitation as the number of rows from x & y will not be the same and recycling will not produce reliable results.